# Set a pre debug event on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I would like to run a task before I start debugging my program in visual studio.
I need to run this task every time I debug my program, so a post-build event is not good enough.

I've looked into the "Debugging" tab of the settings, but there is no such option.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can try (IMO) is experiment with the **Command** property in the ***Debugging*** page of your *Project Properties* ,but i don't think will work.

EDIT: if you want to start a batch file ,do it like this ,

```
yourbatch.bat $(targetPath)
```

and in yourbatch.bat you can call you program like this ,

```
call %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

where %2 ... %3 represent possible programm parameter (supplied by your IDE)

The only thing I am wondering about if your program will debugged directly (I think you may have to attach manually to it in the IDE)

Comment: It sounds like a good idea, but how would you put two commands on the same line ? Say I want to call `myscript.bat` and then `$(TargetPath)`, how would you call both of them on the same command line. Also won't the debugger try to debug `myscript.bat` ?

Comment: @jules put all the commands in a .cmd/.bat file. You can call .bat files from within a .bat file (see http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm for help) using the CALL command.

Comment: Has anyone found out if it will debug the project directly?

Answer (score 1):

Add a pre-build step to the compile options of your "debug" build, and do not have it in the "release" build.
(Edit: Pre-build steps are set in the Build Events section of the project properties)

If you are talking about a function or something in the code then use a pre-compiler flag. For example in your Debug build you probably have "_DEBUG" or something similar as a compiler flag... so in the code you can do

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
doMySpecialTask();
#endif
```

and it will only get called when using a debug build.

EDIT: Moving info up from comment below:
To detect a debugger dynamically at runtime you can use the `IsDebuggerPresent()` function in Windows. Macs have one as well `AmIBeingDebugged()`. This is useful if you want your program to behave differently when debugging, but I don't recommend this unless no other options are useful. Modifying the behaviour of the program when debugging might cause the problem to disappear, or manifest in a different manner.

Comment: But will the pre-build event be called even if I don't need to build the application ?

Comment: @jules No, not if you don't build the application. In that case you can use the `#ifdef` statement instead. For example `doMySpecialTask()` could run a .bat file, or a .cmd file to launch an application, or even launch an application. 
This will work whenever you use a debug build, not just when you build it.

If you need to dynamically detect a debugger always then use the `IsDebuggerPresent` function in Windows. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx